# In APA style, what is the appropriate way to differentiate between two organization divisions that both have the word "and" in their names?

Tags: writing, writing-style

I am writing a paper in APA style.  I am attempting to list two organization divisions of a library:

- Information Technology and Technical Services
- Academic Outreach and Services

How do I write and/or style these in a sentence to clearly define the separation of terms without looking like a poorly written sentence?  I'm not entirely convinced using quotes or italics is correct, but I'm leaning towards italics vs. anything else.

> The two major divisions, “Information Technology and Technical Services” and “Academic Outreach and Services,” ...

vs

> The two major divisions, *Information Technology and Technical Services* and *Academic Outreach and Services*, ...

Normally I wouldn't quote the two, but I'm not sure how else to write it.  Italics would work as well, but I don't know if that's appropriate or not, as the APA style guide doesn't appear to have suggestions for anything corporate/organization-related (4.08, 4.21).  4.21 suggests using italics for clarifying words, so that seems somewhat more appropriate than quotes, but the given example doesn't give me much confidence (the example given is "the *small* group [meaning a designation, not group size]").

Comment: Since this is about style for the article text, not the citations, I removed the [tag:citation-style] tag and replaced it with [tag:writing] and [tag:writing-style].

Comment: @NateEldredge As an aside, it seems that the application of style manuals (e.g., APA, MLA) to non-citation related issues is not readily classified by the existing tagging system. Perhaps there is a need for a new tag.

Comment: I had initially tagged it as writing-style, but someone else changed that.  I agree with @JeromyAnglim that a new tag would be useful, as I was a little confused which tag(s) would be appropriate given the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If following APA style you should not use quotation marks or italics for names of organisations.

You could use an in-line list to make it clear.

To apply this to your example:

> There are two major divisions: (a)  Information Technology and Technical Services and (b) Academic Outreach and Services.